LINEへのリダイレクト後にセッション情報が切れてしまい、継続処理ができない
自社のシステム（.NetFramework4.6）において、LINEへのリダイレクト後にセッション情報が切れてしまい、継続処理ができない状況が発生しております
以下に、問題の詳細を記載いたします。
問題の概要
自社システムより呼び出されたAPI（API Gatewayに紐づくLambda関数）から取得したURLを使用してLINEを表示し、その後LINEからのWebhookを受信し処理を行っております。
しかし、LINEへのリダイレクト後に自社システムに戻る際にセッション情報が切れ、エラーが発生しております。
発生している問題の特徴
この問題は試行回数や端末によって差異が生じ、一貫して発生しているわけではありません。
また、検証環境では事象が起こらず、本番環境でのみ事象を確認しています。
以下施行対象の端末です

iPhone15→OK
iPhone12→OK
iPhone11→NG
別機iPhone11→OK
iPhone13→NG
iPhone8→OK
7.別機iPhone8→NG
8.iPhone14→NG
9.Googlepixel6a→NG（2回目以降OK）
10.Digono→NG

対応済みの事項
セッション管理に関する設定（セッションタイムアウト）や、リダイレクト処理に関するコードを再確認しましたが、解決には至りませんでした。
またFireFoxブラウザでは、強化型トラッキング防止をOFF、chromeブラウザではセーフブラウジングをOFFなどの対応を行いましたが、一部端末では解消しませんでした。
LINEへのリダイレクト後にセッション情報が保持されるような方法や設定について、手順やアドバイスをお教えいただければ幸いです。

他のサイトでも同じ内容の投稿 をされているようですが、予め質問の本文にその旨を明示しておいてもらうとスムーズに回答が付きやすくなると思います。 / 参考: マルチポストとはなんですか？何か問題があるのでしょうか？
